# uitableviewcell separator line not displaying in full width

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to display UITableview custom cell. but my tableview separator does not displaying as expected. I am attaching a screenshot.

[image]

I tried with making UIEdgeInsetZero but it did not worked. can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: can't you show constrain and setting your cell on storyboard

Comment: Well you need to make `separatorInset` to **none** for `UITableView` and in custom cell you need to place UIView of 1px height from bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey All I got the solution.

I override layoutSubviews in my Custom UITableViewCell and the separators are displayed properly.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];

for (UIView *subview in self.contentView.superview.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass(subview.class) hasSuffix:@"SeparatorView"]) {
        subview.hidden = NO;
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `separatorInset` to `UIEdgeInsetZero` is not enough for iOS 8. You should also set `layoutMargins` property of table and cell to `UIEdgeInsetZero`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please kindly change the separator insets by custom. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Remove seperator inset
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }

    // Prevent the cell from inheriting the Table View's margin settings
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:NO];
    }

    // Explictly set your cell's layout margins
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
        [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}
```